# How to avoid demo scene the second time you run an app in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, demo

we are making an app-game in Unity, with a demonstration scene that runs the first time you open the app.
I would like to know how to go directly to the game main scene the second time you run the app and therefore avoid the demo scene.

Thanks

Comment: Do you show the demo scene only to logged in users or everyone?

Comment: Only for logged in users, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PlayerPref](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) to remember that the user has already visited. Something like this in the Awake() of the demo scene:

```
private void Awake(){
  if(PlayerPref.hasKey("returningUser")){
    SceneManager.LoadScene("MainScene");
    return;
  }

  PlayerPref.setInt("returningUser", 1);
  PlayerPref.Save();
}
```